# DialogFragment: How to fix button position on Support Library 23.2.0

Tags: android, android-support-library

I was upgrading my Android app to use the **Support Library v23.2.0** and I'm currently having an issue.

All the `DialogFragment`s that have 3 buttons have a strange button position.

---

### On Support Library v23.0.1 it appears like this:

[image: Correct way]

### On Support Library v23.2.0 it appears:

[image: Wrong way]

I presume it's a **Support Library issue**, and not an actual Android team design option.

### Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature.  This is the new style for AlertDialogs.  Previously, long button text would be cut off, and it looks like that is fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a bug, it's the right behavior according to the Material Design.

Take a look [here](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html#dialogs-specs) (`Side-by-side buttons` and `Stacked full-width buttons` sections).

Your buttons must exceed `128dp`, which is a maximum width for buttons in a 280dp wide dialog.

> **Stacked full-width buttons**
>
> When text labels exceed the maximum button width, use stacked buttons to accommodate the text. Affirmative actions are stacked above dismissive actions.

[image: difference]

Comment: So you mean that the bug was on the previous Support Lib?

Comment: Basically - yes. Maybe it wasn't really a bug, it might have been just a material design principle that hadn't been implemented...

Comment: this is a good answer. When the buttons exceed the width expected for a button the framework will automatically stack your buttons now. So if you want all side by side buttons without something custom, shorten your text for the buttons. @NeTeInStEiN use "Manage", "Download", "Cancel" it gives a cleaner simpler look